# How to put menu buttons on top of a menu bar background

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image

I've searched this on here as well as on google and can't seem to make it work. I'm trying to put images directly on top of another. This is for the menu of the site. I've tried using the z-index, which i believe I am using wrong. So I'm trying to simply set the one image as the background of the div.

here is my current code: 
first the html:

```
<center>
<div id="menu1">
        <a href="index.php"><img id="homebutton" src="./images/newmenu/homebutton1.png"></a>
        <a href="register.php"><img id="registerbutton" src="./images/newmenu/registerbutton1.png"></a>
        <a href='login.php'><img id="loginbutton" src="./images/newmenu/loginbutton1.png"></a>
        <a href="about.php"><img id="aboutbutton" src="./images/newmenu/aboutbutton1.png"></a>
```

now the css:

```
     div#menu1{
            background-image: url('./images/newmenu/menubar.png');
     }
```

The background image which is the solid red bar with gradient does not appear. Here is a screen shot of the page.

[image]

as you can see the buttons load but the background does not. If someone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok after looking closer it seems like the site which is in directory public_html. Also in that directory is my wordpress for the parent site. For some reason it seems to be using the wordpress css file.

Answer (score 0):

Your links have images in them (with the navigation text I assume). The background of those images is going to appear over your background image, so your background image will not be seen.

Comment: All my images are png so that shouldn't be a problem. Also the links do not cover the entire width of the background. The fact that it is set as a background image should keep that from being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have to change the question entirely upon discovering the cause.

Comment: The problem was with the css. It was using the wordpress sytle.css I renamed the css file for the site. After that all the images worked correctly.